# general question regarding ecommerce development

Tags: business

I hope it is appropriate to ask this question here. I was going to ask at stackflow.

A very general question. There are loads of ecommerce web based applications about, such as prostores, eshop, exactabacus.com etc. It appears a lot of them already have atemplate ready (with few options). I am just wondering if there are developers out there that offer custom built ecommerce applications,for both b2c and b2b?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everyone I know (not a scientific sample) who makes money doing that kind of work bases it on an existing CMS (usually Drupal, but probably a biased sample since I'm a Drupal dev).

Frankly, we're past the point where many companies have specific enough needs that it makes fiscal sense for them to have you develop things (a log-in system, shopping cart, etc) that are already out there. It's a better use of their funds to grab the essentials that already exist, then pay someone to customize those and add code for whatever unique needs their use case involves.

Comment: I am from .NET side, is there way to customise code for the customer who perhaps uses PHP or Drupal or any other syntax?

Comment: Absolutely.  If it's open source, you can customize it.  Using Drupal as a specific case, there are APIs for just about everything -- there's (theoretically) no case where you should have to hack core to make your customized code work properly.

Comment: @DiscoDude - If you're from the .Net side of things, take a look at DotNetNuke.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there are quite a few developers out there implementing their own eCommerce solution (actually, I'm one of them). Sure, there are a lot of existing solutions ready to use (commercial and Open Source) but there are always good reasons for implementing your own application.

On the one hand there is ego - you're always better than the other guys, so why use their code? ;-) No, really - I think there are real arguments here, too. Depending on the way you want to use the solution, your need for customizing certain features and for integrating the application with an existing software landscape often justifies a new approach.

I think once you get beyond the big players and take a look at smaller companies you'll find a lot of custom tailored applications.